# Function .C -- argument setup fails compilation

Tags: r

I'm currently learning to call compiled C code in R.  Yesterday I created a function for the infinite pi series that when run in R returns a length 1 numeric vector (pi), which works great. Today I'm working on a function that outputs a variable length numeric vector, the Fibonacci sequence calculated for a user-defined `n`.

In *Writing R Extensions*, it is noted that *"the compiled code should not return anything, except through it's arguments"*.  This is where I'm running into trouble.  I don't know how to set up the following C code, **namely the arguments in the final** `else` **statement**, so that no error is triggered following the call to `system`.

I compiled a slightly different version in a C program and it works.  However, the setup is different for compiling code that is to be called in R.  I had to adjust it to accommodate the specifications for R function `.C`.

How can I change the following function so that is compiles with no warnings or errors and can be called in R function `.C`?

**C code to be compiled:**

```
void fibonacci(int *n, int *ans)
{
  # *ans = 0;  I tried this, didn't work

  if(*n == 1 || *n == 2){
    *ans = 1;
  } else if(*n == 0){
    *ans = 0;
  } else {
    *ans = fibonacci(n - 2) + fibonacci(n - 1); # tried 'ans' in arguments
  }                                             # here, didn't work
}
```

**Error occurs here:**

```
## compile and create shared library
> system('gcc -Wall -g -c -fPIC fibonacciR.c -o fibonacciR.o')
fibonacciR.c: In function ‘fibonacci’:
fibonacciR.c:8:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘fibonacci’
fibonacciR.c:1:6: note: declared here
fibonacciR.c:8:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘fibonacci’
fibonacciR.c:1:6: note: declared here
```

Changing the final `ans` line in the C code to

```
} else {
  *ans = fibonacci(n - 2, ans) + fibonacci(n - 1, ans);
}
```

produces a different error

```
> system('gcc -Wall -g -c -fPIC fibonacciR.c -o fibonacciR.o')
fibonacciR.c: In function ‘fibonacci’:
fibonacciR.c:10:5: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
fibonacciR.c:10:5: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

I'm definitely not an expert C programmer, and I do not know how to ignore an argument.  Additionally, the way this function is set up, when I call it in R it will only return one value. So I presume I need to loop `.C` for the user-defined argument `n`.  Is that correct?

---

**Calls to follow, once I get the error sorted out.**

```
system('gcc -Wall -g fibonacciR.o -shared -o libfibonacciR.so')
## load compiled program into R
dyn.load('libfibonacciR.so')
## create function to call compiled program
fibonacci <- function(n)
{
  .C('fibonacci', as.integer(n), ans = as.integer(ans))$ans
}
## call function - result should be first 10 fibonacci numbers
fibonacci(n = 10)
## expected result
[1]  1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55
```

Comment: The fibonacci() function takes 2 arguments. You're only passing one (the first). Try fibonacci(n - 2, ans) + fibonacci(n - 1, ans)

Comment: Right, I tried that.  It's noted in the comment on the same line.

Comment: And the error remained exactly the same?

Comment: Also note that fibonacci() doesn't return a value, and you're operating over it's return value. That will cause another compiler error after you fix the missing argument issue.

Comment: Yes.  I should probably remove the `c` tag. The setup differs for compilation through R.  Sorry about that.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't be using the `.C` interface, it is old and not recommended. Instead use `.Call()`. Also maybe you don't know about the inline package? You might find http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load Rcpp just to get access to its Rcpp Attributes functionality.  It permits you to write this as (expanded to two lines for display; it really fits on one line):

```
R> cppFunction('double fib(double n) { if (n<2) return(n); 
+                                      else return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);}')
R> fib(10)
[1] 55
R>
```

If you run `cppFunction(..., verbose=TRUE)` you get to see the file it creates.

In general, avoid the `.C()` interface and concentrate in `.Call()`.  This is the very clear recommendation in the NEWS file of the most recent R release:

> ```
> * .C(DUP = FALSE) and .Fortran(DUP = FALSE) are now deprecated, and
>   may be disabled in future versions of R.  As their help has long
>   said, .Call() is much preferred.
> ```

Let's stress the *`.Call()` is much preferred* one more time.  See eg [Hadley's Advanced R Programming draft](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) for more on getting going with `.Call()`. His advice too is to straight to Rcpp.

Comment: Wow, `cppFunction` might just solve all my problems. :)  Thanks a lot.  I have a printed 9/25/2013 version of "Writing R Extensions" and guess I forgot to check to News releases.  Cheers

Comment: It helps to have done it "the long and hard way" as you did. Now that that is behind you, enjoy some tools for higher productivity :)

Answer (score 2):

You already know the errors in the following line.

```
*ans = fibonacci(n - 2) + fibonacci(n - 1); # tried 'ans' in args here,
```

I think, you should write a helper function that does all the work, simplifying both in the process.

```
int fibonacci_helper(n)
{
  if(n == 1 || n == 2){
    return 1;
  } else if(n == 0){
    return 0;
  } else {
    return fibonacci_helper(n-1) + fibonacci_helper(n-2);
  }
}

void fibonacci(int *n, int *ans)
{
  *ans = fibonacci_helper(*n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fibonacci` is declared to take two pointers as arguments, and it doesn't return anything.  But in your `else` block, you're trying to call it with a single integer argument and capture a return value from it.

Try something like this in your `else` block:

```
int n1 = *n - 1;
int n2 = *n - 2;
int ans1;
int ans2;
fibonacci(&n1, &ans1);
fobonacci(&n2, &ans2);
*ans = ans1 + ans2;
```

Also, in your `else if` block, that should be `(*n == 0)`.