# R: C symbol not in load table

Tags: c++, r

I have to call a function written in c++ from R in ubuntu.
There are multiple .cpp files say file1.cpp , file2.cpp , file3.cpp, file4.cpp.
The function to be called(named as function_name) resides in file1.cpp.I used the command in ubuntu--

```
R CMD SHLIB file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp file4.cpp
```

and file1.so was successfully created with other .o files.
Then in Rstudio,I did

```
dyn.load("file1.so")
```

and file was loaded.But when I call the function through-

```
output<-.C("function_name",arg_1,arg_2)
```

I get--
Error in .C("function_name", arg_1,arg_2,  :
  C symbol name "function_name" not in load table
How do i rectify this?Is there anything missing?

Comment: Ensure that you have compiled the function in either 32-bit or 64-bit matching you R installation, e.g supply arguments -m32 for 32-bit to gcc which is called by R.

Comment: Fyi, `.C` is approaching deprecation, I believe.  The convention nowadays is to use `.Call` or `.External`. See Dirk's [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453373/function-c-argument-setup-fails-compilation), and also Hadley's comment.

Comment: Is there anything related to both of them being .cpp files? because when i use the same procedure by having same files as .c files, everything is running as expected

Comment: Be sure and use extern "C" function_name() in your code otherwise the name will be mangled.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the recommendation from @user2976762. I trained on the example from the textbook https://diytranscriptomics.com/Reading/files/The%20Art%20of%20R%20Programming.pdf, Chapter 15. The example from this textbook worked when I renamed the example code file from *sd.cpp* to *sd.c*.
Upd. I did not find, How to use .cpp code (not .c code).
Upd2. My many experiments show that ".C(..." cannot run a c++ shared library, but exclusively c-code.

Comment: This is not too surprising, since C and C++ are completely different languages, even though the book incorrectly conflates them. You can’t just use them interchangeably. Chapter 15 of this book actually doesn’t address C++ code at all, and its example file is called `sd.c`, so I’m not sure why you had a file called `sd.cpp` to begin with.